# Creating a class in python with several methods

Tags: python, class

I have started  learning Python and want to create a class which takes   four numbers  as input and does  division, mutiplication, addition and subtraction. The results should be printed. I made a class, but i don't know how to include different methods.

```
class fraction: 

def __init__(self, numerator1, denominator1, numerator2, denominator2): 
    
    self.numerator1 = numerator1
    self.denominator1 = denominator1
    self.numerator2 = numerator2
    self.denominator2 = denominator2 
    
    
    self.addition_numerator=numerator1*denominator2+numerator2*denominator1
    self.addition_denominator=denominator1*denominator2
    
    
    self.subtraction_numerator=numerator1*denominator2-numerator2*denominator1 
    self.subtraction_denominator=denominator1*denominator2
    
   
    self.multiplication_numerator=numerator1*numerator2 
    self.multiplication_denominator=denominator1*denominator2
    
    
    self.division_numerator=numerator1*denominator2 
    self.division_denominator=denominator1*numerator2


    user_fraction=fraction(int(input("Enter the first numerator: ")), int(input("Enter the first denominator: ")),int(input("Enter the second numerator: ")), int(input("Enter the second denominator: ")))       


    print(user_fraction.__dict__)
```

Comment: What exectly are you trying to achieve? What is your question? What did you try to code? What errors did you get? Your code is not indented, try to put indented codes in order people could help you faster.

Comment: You just took the code you would have written without a class, and shoved it into the `__init__` method of a class and stuck `self.` in front of all your variable assignments. That's not how classes are supposed to be used.

Comment: A `Fraction` class should represent fractions - an instance might represent 3/4, or 7/3 - and the methods would do stuff like add a fraction to another fraction to produce a new fraction, represented by a new instance of `Fraction`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace num1 and num2 with num3 and num4.

```
class fraction:
      def __init__(self,num1,num2,num3,num4):
       self.num1=num1
       self.num2=num2
       self.num3=num3
       self.num4=num4
      def addition(self):
        print(self.num1+self.num2)
        return self.num1+self.num2
      def sub(self):
         print(self.num1+self.num2)
         return self.num1+self.num2
      def div(self):
         print(self.num1/self.num2)
         return self.num1/self.num2
      def mul(self):
         print(self.num1*self.num2)
         return self.num1*self.num2
      def reminder(self):
         print(self.num1%self.num2)
         return self.num1%self.num2


     if __name__ =="__main__":
       object=fraction(1,2,3,4)
       object.addition()
       object.reminder()
```